# Piped command in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I have two simple C programs, A and B. A would run first, then B gets the stdout of A, and uses the stdout of A as its stdin. The simplest possible way make the output from the first program, A, be read by the other program B would be:

```
$> ./A | ./B
```

If I had to describe this command I would say that it is a piped command that take connect reading from a producer to writing to a consumer. Is that a correct description? Is it as simple as that? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes, if `A` is producer and `B` is Consumer process then `A | B` means `A` process output will be input for `B` process and that's the `pipe()` system call concept.

Comment: Common terminology would be to describe `A | B` as a "pipeline".  From the bash man-page (`man bash`) "A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the character |".

Comment: Don't think of it as "A would run first, then B gets the stdout of A".  The whole point is that A and B run concurrently, so "A would run first" is incorrect.  It is quite possible that B runs first (although in the common case it will block on a read before it does much, and then wait for A to produce some output.)

Comment: This has little to do with Linux (please read the description of the tags that you apply!) but a lot with the shell you are using.